# GAS syntax, how to pushl?

Tags: assembly, syntax, gnu-assembler

GAS is rejecting all my pushl's with

> "wrong instruction prefix"

. I can't figure out why...(sample dummy code)

```
.section .text
        .global _start
_start:
        movl $10, %eax
        pushl %eax
        movl $1, %eax
        int $exit
.data
.equ exit, 0x80
```

I also couldn't do

```
int 0x80
```

directly in the script above.It says

> operand size mismatch for `int'

I've tried `int 80H`, doesn't work too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int 0x80` should be `int $0x80` (note the `$`, since it's an immediate operand)

Regarding `pushl`, I'm guessing that you're using a version of the GNU assembler that was configured for 64-bit targets. `push r32` is *non-encodable* in 64-bit mode as you can see in the description for `push` in [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals). You could use `pushq %rax` instead.

However, looking at your code it seems like you're writing a 32-bit application, so you should probably tell the assembler to use 32-bit mode instead (pass `--32` to `as,` or `-m32` to `gcc`).

If you're linking with `ld` you'll also have to specify an emulation mode for `ld` with `-m`, e.g. `-m elf_i386` (to find out which emulation modes you have available, use `ld -V`). An alternative would be to link with `gcc`, e.g. `gcc -m32 foo.o`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are on an `x86_64` architecture, but trying to assemble `x86` specific code. You need to pass the `--32` flag to `gas`:

```
$ as --32 -ofile.o file.asm
```

With this command line, I was able to assemble your code - without the flag, I am getting the `wrong instruction prefix` error.

> I also couldn't do
>
> int 0x80

The `int` instruction requires one immediate operand (the interrupt vector number), and `gas` requires immediate operands to be prefixed with `$` (which you correctly did for your `mov` instructions):

```
int $0x80
```